# ggplot does not display the plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some problems with two plots in particular, and I am not able to find out a solution. I am also attaching the warning messages.

These are the code lines:

```
ggplot(summarise(group_by(dat, dayOfWeek), revenue = sum(TotalSales)), 
       aes(x = dayOfWeek, y = revenue)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'Steel Blue') + 
  labs(x = 'Day of Week', y = 'Revenue (£)', 
       title = 'Revenue by Day of Week') + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Warning message:
Removed 6 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

```
ggplot(summarise(group_by(dat, month), revenue = sum(TotalSales)), 
       aes(x = month, y = revenue)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', 
                                               fill = 'Steel Blue') + 
  labs(x = 'month', y = 'Revenue (£)', title = 'Revenue by month of year') + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Warning message:
Removed 12 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

[image: In here it's how the plot displays]

I have tried to find a solution to the warning message, but every answer i found says "don't worry, it's just a warning message, you can ignore it". The problem is that i can't ignore it, as the data look to not get plotted

Comment: Try `sum(TotalSales, na.rm = T)`

Comment: It works!! I didn't think abt it, as i removed na before. Thank you so much!